# Fingerprint u.a.u 4500 with ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, driver, release, fingerprint

i want to install the drivers for u are u 4500, but it only can be compiled with old kernel versions (2.6 to 3.2) , can you help me to install the drivers on ubuntu with last kernel version.

The sample application of fingerprint cant recognize the device.

Comment: update your question with link to the drivers so we can see if anyone can get them installed under 18.04  ...  alternatively (however I do not know)  possibly you would install the drivers in a docker container running an earlier kernel

Comment: http://downloads.crossmatch.com/u-are-u-sdk-for-linux-v2-2-3-update-dpb02_15_002-32-bit-and-64-bit/
Thank you for answer.
Here are the sdk and drivers for linux.
if someone knows other optios of drivers for u4500 fingerprint,  it would really help me.

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure what problems you are having, but I could compile and install the driver under Ubuntu 18.04. I did get a few errors during compilation, which I fixed as follows:

Error 1:

> /opt/DigitalPersona/urusdk-linux/Linux/drivers/source/usbdpfp/usbdpfp.h:186:5:
>   error: unknown type name ‘wait_queue_t’
>   /opt/DigitalPersona/urusdk-linux/Linux/drivers/source/usbdpfp/usbdpfp.c:606:9:
>   error: implicit declaration of function ‘copy_from_user’; did you mean
>   ‘raw_copy_from_user’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>   --- and a bunch of related compilation errors---

Solution:
In /opt/DigitalPersona/urusdk-linux/Linux/drivers/source/usbdpfp/usbdpfp.h, replace

```
wait_queue_t                    wait;
```

with

```
wait_queue_entry_t                    wait;
```

Error 2:

> opt/DigitalPersona/urusdk-linux/Linux/drivers/source/usbdpfp/usbdpfp.c:2186:22:
>   error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’; did you mean
>   ‘timer_pending’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

Solution:

a) In  /opt/DigitalPersona/urusdk-linux/Linux/drivers/source/usbdpfp/usbdpfp.h, replace:

```
 #include <linux/sched.h>
```

with

```
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
```

b) In /opt/DigitalPersona/urusdk-linux/Linux/drivers/source/usbdpfp/usbdpfp.c, replace:

```
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
```

with

```
 #include <linux/uaccess.h>
```

Now compile and install the module:

```
 $ /opt/DigitalPersona/urusdk-linux/redist/usbdpfp start

$ lsmod |grep dpfp
mod_usbdpfp            45056  0
usbcore               286720  7 mod_usbdpfp,usbhid,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,btusb,uas,ehci_pci
```

Good luck.