# Digital Persona U.are.U 4500 in Ubuntu

Tags: java

Does anyone manage to use the java SDK of DigitalPersona in Ubuntu?

I tried the samples but it can't detect my device.

Comment: are u already install and compile the sdk? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995086/fingerprint-u-a-u-4500-with-ubuntu-18-04